# Putting Data Table into 2 columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

I have a table that contains photos. One photo and its description in each record. I want to create a temp table that has two photos/descriptions per record. So, I need to create a report that has photos displayed in two columns.

This is what I have:

```
 1  Photo1, Description1
 2  Photo2, Description2
 3  Photo3, Description3
 4  Photo4, Description4
```

Here is what I am expecting:

```
 Photo1, Description1, Photo2, Description2
 Photo3, Description3, Photo4, Description4
```

How can I get there using a stored procedure in `SQL Server 2012`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide a lot of details here but here is a possibility. The first cte adds a row number to every row so we can ensure we have a consistent numbering pattern. Then we have a cte to retrieve the odd numbers followed by another cte to get the even numbers. Then we just join them together.

```
with NumberedPhotos as
(
    select Photo
        , Description
        , ROW_NUMBER() over(order by PhotoID) as RowNum
    from SomeTable
)
, OddNumbers as
(
    select Photo
        , Description
        , RowNum
    from NumberedPhotos
    where RowNum % 2 = 1
)
, EvenNumbers as
(
    select Photo
        , Description
        , RowNum
    from NumberedPhotos
    where RowNum % 2 = 0
)
select o.Photo
    , o.Description
    , e.Photo
    , e.Description
from OddNumbers o 
left join EvenNumbers e on o.RowNum = e.RowNum - 1
```

Comment: you missed a comma after your first CTE. You also can't left join on Rownum at the end because you are not selecting them in both your CTE's. .

Comment: Easy to miss these when you can't test because nothing was provided. Would be more helpful to edit the answer instead of just a downvote.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I have cancelled my downvote since you updated your answer.

Comment: Btw, your query doesn't return what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @NepaliRookie what do you mean?

Comment: Well now you updated your query. Previously, you had `o.RowNum = e.Rownum`. So it was returning null in the second photo name and description columns.

Comment: Once again...it would be more helpful if you notice something to edit that response instead of just pointing out that it doesn't work.

Comment: @SeanLange - That is close but it doesn't populate the even number side. I think that is because o.RowNum will never equal e.RowNum. The o.RowNum's are always odd and the e.RowNum's are always even.

Comment: @cmh2001 it does...I edited my answer about 10 minutes ago.

Comment: I was not at all intending to be snotty or hyped up. Sorry you interpreted my comment as such. I know what you mean though that some people get all bent when somebody edits their code. Stupid internet...can't hear the inflection very well. :D

Comment: Sorry if I misinterpreted that! I hear you, it's never easy to "see" what other people are intending to say over the big bulk wires. :o)

Comment: The upside is the OP has two working solutions to their problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Modulo` like @Sean Lange mentioned, but you will want to join back to your table something like this:

```
;WITH NumberedPhotos
AS (
    SELECT photo_name
        ,photo_desc
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY Photo_ID
            ) AS RowNum
    FROM photo_info
    )
SELECT  
     t.photo_name
    ,t.photo_desc
    ,n.photo_name
    ,n.photo_desc

FROM NumberedPhotos n
LEFT JOIN NumberedPhotos AS t ON n.rownum = t.rownum + 1
WHERE n.rownum % 2 = 0;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/485c3/19/0)

Comment: Thanks, I used a combination of both answers at it works magnificently!